# Why I have redirect/refresh with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, xmlhttprequest

I try use Django with XMLHttpRequest, try submitting without refresh page. But I have error in console email is not defined.

This my form > name, email, address, text

**order_create.html**

```
<h2>Create order</h2>
<form method="POST" id="post_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button id="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

After I try use Javascript with XMLHttpRequest

```
document.getElementById('post_form').addEventListener('submit', event => {

    event.preventDefault();

    var body = 'name=' + name + "&email=" + email + "&address=" + address + "&text=" + text;


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/order/', true);
    xhr.send(body); 

    xhr.onload = function() {
        var jsonResp = JSON.parse(this.response);
        if (this.status == 200) {
            alert(jsonResp);
        } else {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    }

});
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^order/$', views.order_create, name='order_create')
]
```

**views.py**

```
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        response_data = {}
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    order=order,
                    product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'],
                    quantity=item['quantity']
                )
            cart.clear_session()

        return JsonResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json", safe=False)
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
        return render(request, 'orders/order_create.html', {'cart':cart, 'form':form})
```

In console have error email is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
    <h2>Create order</h2>
     <form method="POST" id="post_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button id="button">Submit</button>
     </form>
```

```js
let form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", (event)=>{

   // This will help you to diable the defaut property of the form, And stops refresing on the submit 

   if(event && event.preventDefault){
      event.preventDefault();
   }

   let formData = new FormData(form)

   //This code will iterate data from the input elements from your form
   let postData = {};

   for(let [key, val] of formData.entries()){
    if(val) postData[key] = val;
   }


   postData(event.target.action, postData)
  .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))) 
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
})

function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
        referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
    .then(response => response.json()); // parses JSON response into native Javascript objects 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "redirect/refresh" you're talking about is the form doing its default operation: submitting the form. This causes the browser to navigate away from the page, stopping JavaScript from further executing.

To prevent this and have it run your AJAX code on submit instead, use [`element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach a [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) event on the form element. In the handler, use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the form from doing the default form submission operation.

```
referenceToForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  // Prevent the default behavior of the element. In the case of forms,
  // the act of submitting form data.
  event.preventDefault()

  // The rest of your event handling code

})
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I try it, but have error > email is not defined in console, update